# PHP Remove specific URL from html string

Tags: php

I am trying to remove a specific URL from a text string. I have it working for the most part but I need to include both `http` or `https` versions of the link.

```
$link = '&lt;a href=&quot;http://example.com/Tool/document.php?id=208&quot; target=&quot;_BLANK&quot;&gt;Document Requirementsd&lt;/a&gt;';

$result = preg_replace('/<a href=\"http:\/\/' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '\/Tool\/document.php\?id=(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", htmlspecialchars_decode($html));
```

Whats the best way to make sure that both http and https links are stripped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `(http|https):\/\/` to match both http or https!

Comment: Or just `https?://`.
Remember to escape the slashes if you're using those as delimiters.

Comment: Good catch @thomasrutter. I have edited my answer to include the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

So you need

```
$link = '&lt;a href=&quot;http://example.com/Tool/document.php?id=208&quot; target=&quot;_BLANK&quot;&gt;Document Requirementsd&lt;/a&gt;';
$link = '&lt;a href=&quot;https://example.com/Tool/document.php?id=208&quot; target=&quot;_BLANK&quot;&gt;Document Requirementsd&lt;/a&gt;';
```

Right?

You use get the https link by replace assuming http as static

```
//get primary link always http (we need to create http or https isset func)
$link = '&lt;a href=&quot;http://example.com/Tool/document.php?id=208&quot; target=&quot;_BLANK&quot;&gt;Document Requirementsd&lt;/a&gt;';
//making that as https
$https=str_replace('http','https',$link);
//So now you can do whatever you want.
$result = preg_replace('/<a href=\"http:\/\/' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '\/Tool\/document.php\?id=(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", htmlspecialchars_decode($html));
```

If you want to check if the link is http or https, I can write some more code to find out.

Comment: The str_replace will behave incorrectly if the link happens to include the string "http" in it anywhere other than at the start.  It will work if the link is constant, but that could just be sample code.

Comment: So i can re code it as Finding whether the string has http or https ( if http we can replace the http parts https and check for https and if its https we can replace it to http.
Then Output the two Strings https and http